# Getting JSON file from Geoserver using authorization headers results in MIME-type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get JSON data from Geoserver by using jQuery. I need Authorization headers to access the data, but when using the beforeSend (jQuery) callback it gives me this error:

```
"The script from '*url*' is loaded, however the MIME-type ('text/html') is a non-valid Javascript-MIME-type
```

I get this error when using Firefox *(version 66.0.2)*. The data on Geoserver is protected with an username and password. If I abolish the restriction of an username and password, the scripts works. However, when I apply the restriction and use the before Send callback, it gives me above described error.

```
var username = $("input.name").val();
var password = $("input.password").val();

function getJson(data) {
    var myVar1=data.features[0].properties["jan_pollenw"];
console.log(myVar1)}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + btoa(username + ":" + password));},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
    url: 'https://localhost/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&maxFeatures=5&outputFormat=jsonp&format_options=callback:getJson,
    success: getJson
});
```

Comment: Have you checked what's in the HTML?  Could be an error message such as "wrong password" displayed as HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I checked the console-log of Firefox and there it gave above warning. Besides that, there is nothing in the HTML document. Or do I miss something?

Comment: If you're using the browser to check, then check the response in the *network tab* - the console won't tell you what's being returned unless you tell it to and your only console.log is too late in the process.

Comment: Try removing `dataType:'jsonp'` then `console.log(data)` as the first line of 'getJson()' then it might appear in the console.

Comment: Are you sure its a get request you should make and not a POST?

Comment: @freedomn-m, looking at the network tab I see that it gives a 502 proxy error. Does that mean that the proxy is not holding the username and password correctly? Because without authorization it does give me the right response.

Comment: No idea, but at least you now know why it's giving "html is not json" error.

Comment: @freedomn-m, Thank you anyway for your help. It did bring me closer to the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @Anuga, I tried it with a POST request as well, but I got the same 502 proxy error.